# django filter postgres json field variable not defined

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-jsonfield

I am new to working with Django and postgres JSONFields. Using Django 1.11.1
The following view reports a

> name 'snapshot__timestamp' is not defined

Model:

```
class Snapshot(models.Model):
    id = PGUUIDField(primary_key=True)
    snapshot = JSONField(help_text=("Snapshot of config tree values"))
```

View:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    if len(self.request.query_params) > 0:
        try:
            startdate = time.strptime(self.request.query_params.get('startdate', None),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            enddate = time.strptime(self.request.query_params.get('enddate', None), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            return Snapshot.objects.filter(Q(snapshot__timestamp>=startdate) & Q(snapshot__timestamp<=enddate))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            logger.exception(e)  
            return Snapshot.objects.none()
    return Snapshot.objects.all()
```

Example json field entry:

```
{"tree": {"asdf": "values"}, "pollgroup": [1, 3], "timestamp": "2017-7-2 00:00:00"}
```

All of the examples I have found show the modelfield__json key in the query.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`timestamp` is a field of Snapshot. Use:

```
Snapshot.objects.filter(
    Q(timestamp__gte=startdate) & 
    Q(timestamp__lte=enddate)
)
```

Check [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups) about field lookups.

Comment: I still get `name 'timestamp' is not defined`

Comment: If i remove the '>' and '<' symbol it works with `snapshot__timestamp`.  WTF am I missing?

Comment: how I did not see that. Please check my edited answer